# "Mortarboard" badge- new?

Tags: support, badges

I recently was awarded the "Mortarboard" bronze badge. It's for earning more than 200pts in a day. Turns out I had done this in the past back in October of 2011. 
Is this a new badge? Is the algorithm only applied from the point of implementation forward? Just trying to understand how this works...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know how long it's been around, but it's not a recent change.

Looking at your reputation history, the 2011-10 day when you earned more than 200 points wouldn't count because 100 of those points were an "association bonus".

> Reputation points earned for associating accounts or for accepting other users' answers to your own questions do not count for the [mortarboard] badge.

See [List of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions/68258#68258) for more information.